# Trying to set up deep linking, page referenced not being found

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to understand the basics of deep linking when in the development stage, by following this guide (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking/). When I try to run the command suggested by the guide, the simulator hits me with a "there was a problem loading the requested app" then shows the address that I was trying to access. When I check the expo client, the cli isn't running, im not sure if this is a side-effect of the failure or the reason why it's failing as if `npx uri-scheme open exp://127.0.0.1:19000/login --ios` doesn't start expo.

I really wouldn't doubt it if the issue is in the way I tried and set it up. Heres the code.

```
 
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import Login from "./screens/login";
import * as Linking from 'expo-linking';


function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      <Button title="login" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Login')} />
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const prefix = Linking.makeUrl('/');

function App() {

  const linking = {
    prefixes: [prefix],
    config: {
      screens: {
        Login: "/login"
      }
    },
  };

  return (
    <NavigationContainer linking={linking} fallback={<Text>Loading content...</Text>}>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Stack.Screen hide name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen hide name="Login" component={Login} />

      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

note that the login page is another file, just containing text for test purposes.

I'm pretty positive this is incorrect is probably many ways. How I understood this is that when the /login follows the host path, it would link the user to the login page. What am I missing? Thanks!